# My redirect from http to https in Nginx not working

Tags: nginx, redirect

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name www.21cl.ca 21cl.ca;
    return 301 https://21cl.ca$request_uri;
}

server {
        server_name 21cl.ca;
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        ssl_certificate /srv/ssl/2100computerlane_net.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /srv/ssl/21ca.key;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;
        access_log /srv/www/www.2100computerlane.net/logs/access.log;
        error_log /srv/www/www.2100computerlane.net/logs/error.log;
        root /srv/www/www.2100computerlane.net/public_html;

        location / {
                index index.html index.htm index.php;
                autoindex on;
                autoindex_exact_size off;
        }

        location ~* \.php$ {
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        }
}
```

http://www.21cl.ca is being forwarded to https://www.21cl.ca not https://21cl.ca like instructed.

Note this works fine when I do it with my dot net and dot com domains.

Comment: I think it has been cached in the browser try it in private or incognito window, It is redirecting properly for me

Comment: Okay that's probably the issue then. I am trying to fix another problem currently so the site is down so I can't test it. Thanks

Comment: Jaswanth - it is working in a private windows so it was the browser caching. If you make that an answer I will accept it. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has been cached in the browser try it in private or incognito window, It is redirecting properly for me